# In Angular Getting error - "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './internal/Observable' "

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, observable, node-modules

I am getting below error while running angular application.
I have just upgrade angular from 13 to 14 version.

```
$ npm run start

> Wallets@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './internal/Observable'
Require stack:
- C:\Wallet\AngularUpgradeV1\CodeWallet\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\rxjs\index.js
- C:\Wallet\AngularUpgradeV1\CodeWallet\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\api.js
- C:\Wallet\AngularUpgradeV1\CodeWallet\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\index.js
- C:\Wallet\AngularUpgradeV1\CodeWallet\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\Wallet\AppData\Local\Temp\1\ng-ncIJTe\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Comment: Can anyone please suggest here ?

Comment: did you delete the node_modules, and redo `npm i` ?

Comment: yes I did it multiple times

Comment: can you check if you have an `import from 'rxjs/internal/xxxxxx';` in your project ?

Comment: I checked in codebase no such import is available.

Answer (score 0):

**Just run :**

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

**And the Import it as below provide it in imports array in respective Module file :**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: I executed the same but still failing.                                                                             

npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@14.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"14.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cdk@">=15.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@15.0.0-beta.42
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!   @angular/flex-layout@"15.0.0-beta.42" from the root project

Comment: How can i make sure that I have added the correct dependency version wrt angular 14. Is there any way to check that?